# Magento 2 : Email template issue

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I am sending a string from helper file to email template

```
 $templateVars = [
                'store_credit_amount' => $storeCredit 
            ]; // $15
```

In email template html file i use it like

```
<p style=" text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: arial;">
                           

 You’ve got < span style ="color: #F3198F;"> {{var store_credit_amount}} </ span> in store credit.</p>
```

But in email template which i get on email id, it shows span tag separately

When i add static number in email template it appears fine.
Not sure how to solve this, any thoughts ?

Comment: can you please share whole code you are using to print the line.

Comment: It has been fixed.
Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed using `{{var store_credit_amount | escape }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   <p style="" text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: arial;"">
        {{trans ""You’ve got ""}}
        <span style=""color: #F3198F"">{{var store_credit_amount}}</span>
        {{trans ""in store credit.""}}
    </p>
```